# Add Local rate limiting using EnvoyProxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I setup Global rate limiting on a K8s cluster (with Istio on minikube).

I followed this repo https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22068#issuecomment-633036911
as it summarizes this issue well and makes global rate limiting work.

It works really well
[image: global rate limit works]

How would I add local rate limiting to envoy proxies (service to service)? The docs are pretty light and confusing to a newbie like me https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/network_filters/local_rate_limit_filter

Any config yaml would be appreciated. I'd like to make it granular (match a specific version of a service)
Thank you

Comment: Not sure but should be  possible throguh conditional rate limit where u can specify the source. https://istio-releases.github.io/v0.1/docs/tasks/rate-limiting.html

Comment: unfortunately rate limiting with Mixer in Istio is deprecated
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/
^ this is the up to date version of the link you shared

Comment: Have you tried to change the [workload](https://github.com/aboullaite/service-mesh/blob/master/4-policy/rate-limiting/rate-limit-envoy-filter.yaml#L54-L56) from ingress gateway to a specific service, on which should the rate limiting actually work?

Answer (score 3):

I've put an example of using envoy rate limiting with istio. it may be useful https://github.com/aboullaite/service-mesh

Comment: It's this issue :D. I asked the Q here too to see if someone has solved it.
https://github.com/aboullaite/service-mesh/issues/5

Comment: @Aboullaite its great what you did there. Its really helpful. Can you please add some local rate limiting demo there?